# Laravel Mail::raw custom variables

Tags: php, laravel

I have this snippet that sends email with the mail gun API that i have set in env. It all sends but i now want to pick the variables from the user and also set some other information based on the input

```
$name       =  $request->name;
$name2      =  'hello';
$email      =  $request->email;
$message    =  $request->message;

Mail::raw($message, function($message)
{
    $message->from('hello@hello.com', 'In-app Correspondence By -- ')->subject('Welcome!');
    $message->to('pr@example.com')->cc('me@gmail.com');
});
```

The problem is when i put `$message->to($email)->cc('me@gmail.com');` that gives an internal server error, but the code above works fine.

Th email is fine I checked but is there. I would like to also put reply-to to the message and insert the $email variable. So far reply-to and even placing $email on the subject is leading to an internal server error.

What could be the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to pass a variable to a closure in PHP you have to use the `use` keyword. So try this:

```
$name       =  $request->name;
$name2      =  'hello';
$email      =  $request->email;
$message    =  $request->message;


Mail::raw($message, function($message) use ($email)
{
    $message->from('hello@hello.com', 'In-app Correspondence By -- ')->subject('Welcome!');

    $message->to($email)->cc('me@gmail.com');
});
```